# Session ID changes in Kohana 3.x

Tags: php, session, php-5.3, kohana-3

I am developing a Facebook app in Kohana 3.x. Now client requirement is to make Sessions GET based. but it is having a problem. I am using

```
ini_set( 'session.use_cookies_only', false );
ini_set( 'session.use_trans_sid', true );
session_start();
```

in index.php and assuming that it should do that, it is concatenating PHPSESSID with href of a tag. But when page refresh with a PHPSESSID, PHPSESSID in GET and session_id() are different. I did that in normal PHP and it worked fine. So I think it is some problem happening in Kohana 3.x as it seems that Kohana use sessions differently and I am also starting session in index.php but not sure. What do I need to convert session to GET instead of cookie in Kohana 3.x?

I want to mention that I am using 5.3.2 on server where Kohana is running, I think this might be related to my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transient sessions do not appear to work in 5.3.3. See this for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#99619

You can try using kohana's sessions library. Not sure if provides support for transient sessions.

Comment: Yah, there for, I am askinh about Kohana sessions, that how this work in Kohana if this work in kohana 3.1

Comment: Although it is not exact answer what I was looking for but it leads me to some where better than where I was, so marking it a correct and only answer to my question :)